# How to copy all the data from current directory to desired directory except one folder using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, copy, dynamic-programming

I want to copy my all data including directories, sub directories, files, sub files from **source directory** to **destination directory** named "**kit**" excluding only one folder named "**kit**" and its internal data using **Ruby**.

Eg:

I want to copy **my_data_1, my_data_2, my_data_3** directories including their sub files and sub directories into **kit/backup** folder excluding **kit** folder itself.

Scenario :

```
    \kit
        \backup

    \my_data_1
             \bin
                 \data

    \my_data_2
             \images
                   \images.png

    \my_data_3
             \softwares
                       \my_data.exe
```

Code :

```
class Kit < Thor
desc "add" , "add command"
method_option :add, :alises => "-add"
    def add
    location = Dir.pwd
    current = location.split('/')
    current_dir = current.last
    puts current_dir
    all_data = Dir['**/*']
    all_data.delete('kit')
    puts all_data     // Code is working upto here

    destination = Dir.chdir("kit")
    FileUtils.cp_r "#{all_data}", "#{destination}"
    end
end
```

> Implementation must be in Ruby. For fast processing multithreading can also be implemented.

Comment: SO is not a “write code for me” community. You need at least to show what you have already tried.

Comment: Please now review the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dir['**/**'].reject { |f| f =~ /\Akit(?=$|\/)/ }
```

The above will return the list of files, excluding those in top-level `kit` directory. I assume this code is to be run from within the top-level directory. To change directory, use [`Dir#chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Dir.html#method-c-chdir).

To copy everything into another dir:

```
Dir.mkdir(dir = '/tmp/test') unless File.directory? dir

Dir['**/**'].reject { |f| 
  f =~ /\Akit(?=$|\/)/ 
}.each { |f| 
  FileUtils.cp_r f, dir 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have done the excluding part. I am unable to copy the directories into the kit directory.

Answer (score 0):

For list directory content you can use [Dir](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Dir.html) then iterate on results and use [copy](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html%23method-c-copy_file) for copy your file and folders.